# Wordpress - 401 Authorization Required

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

I recently renewed my domain name after it expired. However, when I try to view my website, a login box popups.

This is new. I tried putting in my wordpress admin username and password all to no avail. Infact I get a '401 Authorization Required' error.

I have been at this for some days now. I contacted my hosting provider. They said they could view my website and that everything is fine. They however instructed me to clear my browser cache and cookies, which I have done. Still, the problem persist.

I tried viewing the site with an IP proxy site and truly I could see my website without any errors or login pop up box.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 401 request usually means that your client (e.g. your web browser) is not able to authenticate itself with the server therfore cannot view the resource.

> You have cleared your cache and cookies and you're prompted by a login
>   box,  following this a 401 error appears. The site is viewable from
>   proxy.

Things to check,

- Flush your DNS
- Are the login details correct? its possible to get this error from incorrect logins
- Check the URL for errors, make sure you're using the intended url
- Try deactivating your wordpress plugins if problems still persist

Any further information you can provide, including images would help a lot.